# Dequeue Method C#

Tags: c#

I designed a simple Windows forms application where a user enters his name and clicks on Add, which will add his name to the queue. There's also a remove button when pressed it dequeues his name.

The obstacle I'm facing is when dequeuing, the "head" value increases as expected, and numItem decreases as expected but the name is not removed from the queue.

Code:

Queue class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AssessedExerciseWeek1_2_Task1A
{
    class Queue
    {
        private readonly int maxsize = 10;
        private string[] store;
        private int head = 0;
        private int tail = 0;
        private int numItems;

        public Queue()
        {
            store = new string[maxsize];
        }

        public Queue(int size)
        {
            maxsize = size;
            store = new string[maxsize];
        }

        public void Enqueue(string value)
        {
            numItems++;
            store[tail] = value;
            if (++tail == maxsize)
            {
                tail = 0;
            }
        }

        public string Dequeue()
        {
            string headItem;
            numItems--;
            headItem = store[head];
            if (++head == maxsize)
            {
                head = 0;
            }

            return headItem;

        }

        public bool IsEmpty()
        {
            return tail == 0; //returns the boolean result of the comparison between head and 0
        }

        public bool IsFull()
        {
            return tail == maxsize;
        }
        public int CountQueue() //counts the number of items inside the queue
        {
            return tail - head;
        }

        public int Tail //property
        {
            set { this.tail = value; }
            get { return tail; }
        }

    }
}
```

Remove Button Code:

```
private void RemoveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            names.Dequeue(); //names is a new instance of the queue (declared on top of the windows form code)
        }
```

Comment: That is the way you programmed it.  Adding store[head] = null; to Dequeue() is not necessary, it will eventually be overwritten.  Focus instead on making it safe, protecting against calling Dequeue() when Enqueue() was not called and calling Enqueue() too often.

Comment: Alternatively you could just use `Queue<int>` unless this is HW that requires you to write your own queue.

Comment: @juharr I have to write my own queue

Comment: Have you considered using a linked list? That way you only need a pointer to head and tail items, and each queue item contains a pointer to the next.

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry, but I don't get why the name is not being dequeued

Comment: @NatWallbank I am aware of linked lists but I must write my Queue

Comment: You should draw out what happens on a piece of paper, and it'll be clear why the value isn't removed as well as why it doesn't matter. "it will eventually be overwritten", as Hans says.

Comment: @ZCoder I believe the suggestion was to implement your own queue by using a linked list as the data structure, which is probably the best option in terms of space complexity.

Comment: _"the name is not removed from the queue"_ -- what do you mean by that? There are at least two possible interpretations: the value (the string reference itself) still exists in the _array_ that your queue data structure uses, or the value is actually _produced_ later while dequeuing values. Not counting your lack of a check on the current queue length, I don't see how the latter could happen. The former may or may not be a problem, depending on your assignment (the object won't be garbage-collected, but it also shouldn't be produced by the queue, ...

Comment: ... until you violate the contract of the queue by dequeuing from it when it's already empty...the former may or may not be a real concern, the latter is a concern only if you misuse the queue). Bottom line: your question is unclear. Provide a [mcve], state precisely what that code does, what you want it to do instead, and what _specifically_ you need help with.

Comment: @insane_developer: _"which is probably the best option in terms of space complexity"_ -- huh? a linked list will take way more space than an array. The "complexity" is identical (assuming by "complexity" you mean the memory-allocation equivalent of big-O notation), being linear with the number of elements in both cases. But a linked list is generally going to take at least twice as much memory space as an array-based queue data structure.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I am basing my comment on the assumption that you don't know the number of elements you will be storing, for which a list, which is based on an array, will have to re-allocate space as it grows, by doubling each time. I'm not sure why a singly linked list will take more space of an array with unused slots.

Comment: @insane_developer: "complexity" ignores small effects. In the code above, max size is pre-determined to be 10 elements. So we can assume that there will at some point be a linked list with 10 nodes. To the first approximation, this 10-node linked list will take twice the space as an array holding the same data. It's true that in the more general case, the two will be roughly equivalent, but even there an array-based approach (with the doubling-allocation scheme you describe...i.e. like .NET's `Queue<T>`) will be _at worst_ the same as a linked list, and on average significantly better.

Comment: @ZCoder What do you really mean by *it's not removed from the queue*? How would it? You never overwrite the value on Deque (and it may not be necessary, if you keep your head and tail pointing to the correct indexes). But you should make sure, that you can't dequeue on an already empty queue. Because that may make your head point to an element which contains a previously dequed item.

Comment: If we're taking about complexity, i think we should probably focus on complexity from a code comprehension point of view, which would be far more valuable to someone at this stage of their career than the unlikely case of needing to care about whether an array or linked list consumes more storage.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing this with arrays is not the best option, but if you want to do it, then the problem is that you are not defining a way to now if a 'space' of the array is empty. I used null to achieve that.
Change your dequeue method to this:

```
    public string Dequeue()
    {
        string headItem;
        headItem = store[head];
        if (headItem != null)
        {
            store[head] = null;
            numItems--;
            if (++head == maxsize)           
                head = 0;           
        }
   
        return headItem ?? "There are no more objects in the queue";
    }
```

You sould probably consider adding a validation to your Enqueue() method to make sure no new strings are added if they array is full because, currently, your first element gets overwritten when the max size is surpassed.

Also, check for different ways to implement this, like using LinkedList, as suggested in the comments, or creating your own Node class to 'connect' objects.